# Add rules to Minesweeper until you can start with nothing

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, optimization, minesweeper

Think of classic Minesweeper game, with the following list of restrictions on the placement of mines:

- **C** (Connected): All mines are connected via 8-way neighborhood (orthogonal and diagonal).
- **Q** (Quad): Every 2x2 subgrid contains at least one mine.
- **T** (Triplet): No three mines are adjacent on a line (row, column, or diagonal). Think of Tic-Tac-Toe.
- **O** (Outside): All mines are connected to the outside via 4-way neighborhood (orthogonal), and all non-mine cells are connected via 4-way neighborhood.

Here are some examples under each restriction: (`X` are mines, and `.` are cells without mines)

| C | Q | T | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ``` XXX.. ...X. .XX.. ..X.. .X.XX ``` | ``` .X..X ..X.. .X..X .X.X. .XX.X ``` | ``` X...X X..X. .X..X XX... ...XX ``` | ``` .XX.X ....X .X... XXXX. X.... ``` |

Now, find the unique combination of two restrictions that allow you to open a cell with 100% certainty on a large enough grid. What kind of cell(s) can you open, and what is the minimum size of such a grid?

---

Note: The answer to this puzzle spoils how to get a specific achievement in *14 Minesweeper Variants* (2022) by Artless Games.

Comment: Are you saying there is only one unique combination of restrictions? And one specific grid size?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A grid that satisfies the condition is

> a 7x7 grid with **Triplet** and **Outside** restrictions.

We can click on

> **the center cell.**
>
>  Indeed, if it was a mine, then we would need to connect it to the outside border. To progress towards the border from the center mine, we must do some sort of S shape in any direction:
>
>  [image]
>
>  As we can see, we end up being stuck because of the triplet rule. Hence, the center cell cannot be a mine, so it's safe to click on it!

Comment: That was quick. Have you already played the 14 Minesweeper Variants?